# Features for binary time-series event prediction

Tags: time-series, classification, feature-selection, signal-processing

This question is somewhat inspired by the answer to [Features for time series classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50807/features-for-time-series-classification).

The difference to that question is that I have a dataset with multi-dimensional time-series where I have several binary-valued features, not continuously-valued features.

Moreover, I do not need to classify the whole series but rather classify the small windows (length 10-100 while the whole time-series is rather of length ~20000).

The question: which of the features mentioned in the attached answer would still apply in the case of binary features?

- Does it make sense to perform  some frequency-domain analysis (eg. to know how fast the binary values are changing) and how to choose a window for DFT?
- What about other mentioned features such as skewness, kurtosis and parts of ARIMA model?